# Nginx shuts down every 3 months because of the same failed binding error

Tags: linux, nginx, http, service

I am running a `Symfony` website on a server, using `Nginx` configured with `Let's Encrypt`. Everything goes fine when I start the server (always with `sudo service nginx start` / `restart`)

But every 3 months, I notice that the website is down. When I check the logs, it's always the same :

```
2018/12/23 00:23:53 [notice] 22167#22167: signal process started
2018/12/23 00:23:53 [error] 22167#22167: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/12/23 00:23:54 [emerg] 22194#22194: still could not bind()
2018/12/23 00:23:57 [alert] 22169#22169: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I know that other people had the same issue, but at startup. For me, something triggers it later...

Also :

```
uname -a
Linux vps460780 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And when running nginx:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6644/nginx: master

sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7021/nginx: master
```

I will be happy to post any other configuration file.

Comment: Probably every three months let’s encrypt renews your TLS certificates and to effectuate the renewal it issues a restart (which fails) - take a look at your post renewal settings

Answer (score 2):

Your Let's Encrypt post hook should *reload* nginx, not *restart* it, i.e.:

```
--post-hook "systemctl reload nginx"
```

To get out of your current situation, kill all existing nginx processes and then restart nginx, i.e.:

```
killall nginx
systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: I am not sure what Let's Encrypt does. The only thing I know is that in `/etc/cron.d/` theres a `certbot` file with "`0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew`"

Comment: That's a rather bizarre crontab entry. It probably also has no effect, as that directory exists on all modern systems.

Answer (score 1):

I had/have the same issue and I found that I had another cron job running (as root) which runs `certbot renew --post-hook="systemctl reload nginx"`. I think I ran through a tutorial before to get it installed initially which told me to add this cron entry, but things have changed since then and it installs its own.

Still need to verify this fixes it (wait months to see if it happens) but I suspect that this is it.